# htaccess rewrite rules not working

Tags: .htaccess

I have created a subdomain of a site. The subdomain is pointed to a folder on the root.

For some reasons, the following rewrite rules are not working. Two segment urls are working. One is not working and more than two is not working. Please see the urls below.

- `subdomain.domain.com/register` (not working)
- `subdomain.domain.com/temp/register` (working)

When i have two segments created dynamically, they are not working.

- `subdomain.domain.com/dynamic1/dynamic2` (not working)

.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule     (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

#FOR REPLACING .HTML EXTENSION (WORKS FINE)
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ $1.html

#FOR REPLACING .PHP EXTENSION (NOT WORKING)
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1.php
```

Let me know if you don't understand this question.

Comment: Add `[L]` after each of the `RewriteRule` to stop matching after the first match (I think that is your issue).  To debug where they are attempting to redirect to, temporarily add `[L,R=301]`. The R will force it to redirect the browser...

Answer (score 2):

Like Michael Berkowsk suggests, you probably want to add `L` flags to the end of your rules so that you end rewriting when the rule has been applied. Other than that, the 2 segment rule that you have only uses the first as a backreference, I assume you want to use both? Try changing your rules to look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /

# the HTTP redirect
RewriteCond     %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule     (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

#FOR REPLACING .HTML EXTENSION (WORKS FINE)
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

#FOR REPLACING .PHP EXTENSION 
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ location.php?li_id=$1&lid=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I did have an issue with two segments in the url. I currently have test.php file which has two query strings.

test.php?id=segment1&value=segment2

With the rules above, i need the url to display as
domain.com/segment1/segment2

The above rule was failing. Please see the rule below i am using.

RewriteRule   ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ location.php?li_id=$1&lid=$2 [L]

Comment: @VasuKireeti Wasn't clear you wanted a **routing** rule. Just add that rule to the end along with some conditions.

Comment: ya.. but the rules above are blocking this condition to work with two segments.

Comment: @VasuKireeti It only blocks them *if* there is a matching php or html file (the `-f` check). Though it's still possible if you went to `http://domain/foo/bar` with the intention of going to `/location.php?li_id=foo&lid=bar` but there **just so happens** that there is a php file at `/foo/bar.php`. If this case is an issue, then you need something unique in front of the 2 arguments in order to differentiate it from a php or html file.